# Unable to install Streamsets in mac

Tags: streamsets

i am trying to install Streamsets in my mac. while i try to start the streamsets by this command: `streamsets-datacollector-3.4.3/bin/streamsets dc` getting following exception:

```
Abnormal exit: java.lang.RuntimeException: The permissions of the realm file '/usr/local/hadoop/streamsets-datacollector-3.3.1/etc/form-realm.properties' should be owner onlyCheck STDERR for more details
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the file `/usr/local/hadoop/streamsets-datacollector-3.3.1/etc/form-realm.properties` should be accessible to the owner only. You can set this via:

```
chmod 600 /usr/local/hadoop/streamsets-datacollector-3.3.1/etc/form-realm.properties
```